# Exception for comparing data

Tags: java, exception, loops

Getting Index out of bound exception for

```
    for (int recordData = 0; recordData < recordDataList.size(); recordData++)
    {
        RecordData nextRecordData = recordDataList.get(recordData + 1);
        if (nextRecordData.getRespondentId() !=     
            recordDataList.get(recordData).getRespondentId()) {
            rowDataNumber++;
        }
    }
```

Here size is 3. But i need to compare third data with second also.
I have modified my like

```
    for (int i = 1; i < recordDataList.size(); i++) {
                         RecordData recordData = recordDataList.get(i - 1);
                RecordData nextRecordData = recordDataList.get(i);
                         commentData = recordData.getCommentText();
if (nextRecordData.getRespondentId() != recordData
                        .getRespondentId()) {
                    rowDataNumber++;
                }
}
```

the size is three i am getting only first two data in commentData,the third data is not getting shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are comparing a value with the next value, there needs to be a next value.

You need to use

```
for (int i = 0; i < recordDataList.size() - 1; i++) {
    RecordData recordData = recordDataList.get(i);
    RecordData nextRecordData = recordDataList.get(i + 1);
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i < recordDataList.size(); i++) {
    RecordData recordData = recordDataList.get(i - 1);
    RecordData nextRecordData = recordDataList.get(i);
```

Comment: I have edited the code its not working for last value ,the last data is not coming

Comment: What are you going to compare the last value with? There is no "next" to the last.

Comment: Consider i am having three string in the list a,b,c i am comparing each in the loop.Just two increment row number .i need to show all the three data using the above loop.

Comment: You want to compare `a` with `b` and `b` with `c`. What other comparison do you need?

Comment: i am checking if next data is not equal then add a new row in excel and dispaly 'a' /'b'/'c ,if the list has all same dta then no increment.In my excel now i can see a and b data but not c

Comment: Are you says you don't see `b` compared with `c` and that it loops only once? If it loops twice you must be seeing `c` as the next record.